# Redesignated students

Tags: knowledge

Class 6F at **Farthingbottom School** was very unusual this year. All the students had transferred from a School in the USA. Today was their first history lesson with Professor Flavanna.

"Welcome, children! I have observed that you all have nice alliterative names from good military families but, for the purposes of my class, I need to assign you all with new surnames. You shall now be known as:

- Arthur Charlestown
- Audrey Burnham
- Barbara Reading
- Brian Beverley
- Clive Salisbury
- Colin Leeds
- Unwin Clare
- Wendy Castleton"

"There are two of you who I think are in the wrong class, but if I have to teach you, you shall be know as:

- Boris St. Francis
- Steven Rosales"

"Now open your copies of *All Hell Let Loose* at chapter one."

---

**Question:** What are the children's real surnames?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am quite confident that the answer is correct.

> Based on the clues.. history, alliteration, army

Arthur Charlestown

> -> Arthur Abbot ->

Audrey Burnham

> -> Audrey Aulick

Barbara Reading

> -> Barbara Bailey

Brian Beverley

> -> Brian Branch

Clive Salisbury

> -> Clive Claxton

Colin Leeds

> -> Colin Conner

Unwin Clare

> -> Unwin Upshur

Wendy Castleton

> -> Wendy Ward

Why

> Apparently the surnames assigned are the names of [USS Town-class destroyers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town-class_destroyer)

Boris St. Francis

> -> Boris Bancroft
>  Note : HMCS St. Francis was transferred to Royal Canadian Navy

Steven Rosales

> -> Steven Stembel
>  Note : USS Stembel was loaned to Rebpublic of Argentina on 7th Aug 1961

I guess that completes the answer. A very interesting format of the question though. Thanks for asking.

Comment: I was concerned that this would prove a bit too obscure, however you proved me wrong in 11 minutes! You've left 2 pupils out of your answer, though.

Comment: @GordonK Thank you for the patience. Have completed the answer.

Comment: Yes - all correct. You didn't even need to use the Professor's name.